# Are there any proteins assembled from non-adjacent parts of the genome?

Tags: genetics, proteins, introns, exons

Many proteins are assembled from multiple exons with the introns between adjacent exons being spliced out. But are there any proteins that have unrelated to them exons in the middle of their sequence?

I think the equivalent question would be: are there any protein-coding genes (in any species) that are broken in two or more parts by another protein-coding gene(s)?

Comment: Not directly related to the question as you have asked it, but do consider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_quaternary_structure as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you are talking about [trans-splicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans-splicing). This does indeed happen. It is fairly common in protist organisms, though in humans it is quite rare. For more information about how this process works, including mechanisms in vertebrate organisms, see this [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4824033/).

Here is one model from that last paper for how it works:
[image]

Comment: Yes, this is what I was thinking about. Thank you!